# Easiest way to find/replace in a file using a list?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file, foo.txt, and a regexp I want to find in that file. Each time I find the regexp, I want to take a line from another file, bar.txt, and substitute it in for the regexp match I found in foo.txt. Basically I want to do find/replace, but each time I replace I want the next replacement text to come from the next line in bar.txt.

Is there any easy shell magic to do this?

Comment: I find your problem definition very difficult to follow. Do you have examples of inputs/outputs?

Comment: @ChrisDown: Sorry about that, I've rephrased, think it's clearer now.

Comment: Do you want the entire line replaced, or just what the regular expression matches within the line?

Comment: @Omnifarious: Just what the regex matches

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, maybe something like:

```
awk '{getline repl < "second-file"; sub(/regexp/, repl); print}' < first-file
```

Or if `regexp` may appear several times per line or not on every line:

```
perl -pe 's/regexp/chomp($r=<STDIN>);$r/ge' first-file < second-file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pe '
    BEGIN {
        open IN, "<replacements" or die $!;
    }

    s/pattern/
        $tmp = <IN>;
        chomp $tmp;
        $tmp
    /xe;
' filename
```

Comment: From the problem description it sounds like maybe the pattern will have to be modified to `^.*(?:pattern).*$' because I think the person asking the question wants the entire line replaced. But otherwise this is an excellent answer.

Comment: I don't think so, actually.  The question was clearer on this point before it was edited, though, so perhaps the OP can clarify if they did want to replace entire lines.